updatedb / locate is not including my attached drive even though it's not excluded in updatedb.conf
I have a 4-terabyte ext4 drive that is mounted on startup to a location within my home folder. Per the /etc/updatedb.conf, there is no reason this should be excluded; however the locate command is unable to access it. The only thing that might cause this that I can see is PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS, but I have no idea what that means. I've looked up what a bind mount is and I don't understand it at all.
Is my drive a bind mount?

Or is there something else going on?
I see in this post from a comment by kevinmicke that while the syntax for files in /etc/cron.daily is different nowadays, there was at least back then a line /usr/bin/updatedb -f "$nodevs" that seems to exclude devices, possibly including all external drives regardless of mount point or filesystem. If this was carried over to the new syntax it might explain why this happens on the daily cronjob, but does not explain why the drive is excluded even when the command is run manually with no arguments.
Edits:
I'm running Pop OS 22.04.

How exactly is the drive mounted?

I'm not sure I understand the question. All the configuration I've ever done on the way the drive is mounted is in the GNOME Disks screenshot. Mount at system startup is checked, mount point is set to within my user folder, drive is set to identify as label.
/etc/updatedb.conf:
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /var/lib/os-prober /var/lib/ceph /home/.ecryptfs /var/lib/schroot"
PRUNEFS="NFS afs autofs binfmt_misc ceph cgroup cgroup2 cifs coda configfs curlftpfs debugfs devfs devpts devtmpfs ecryptfs ftpfs fuse.ceph fuse.cryfs fuse.encfs fuse.glusterfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse fuse.mfs fuse.rclone fuse.rozofs fuse.sshfs fusectl fusesmb hugetlbfs iso9660 lustre lustre_lite mfs mqueue ncpfs nfs nfs4 ocfs ocfs2 proc pstore rpc_pipefs securityfs shfs smbfs sysfs tmpfs tracefs udev udf usbfs"

mount | grep /mount/point:
/dev/sda on /home/spyndling/bigboy4tb type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,x-gvfs-show)

dpkg -l "*locate*" | grep ^.i:
ii  plocate        1.1.15-1ubuntu2 amd64        much faster locate

/usr/sbin/updatedb.plocate --debug-pruning 2>&1 | grep home:
/home/.ecryptfs\000
 `/home' (93 on 32) is `/' of `/dev/nvme0n1p4' (259:4), type `ext4'
 `/home/spyndling/Windows main' (96 on 93) is `/' of `/dev/nvme0n1p3' (259:3), type `fuseblk'
 `/home/spyndling/bigboy4tb' (99 on 93) is `/' of `/dev/sda' (8:0), type `ext4'
 => adding `/run/timeshift/backup' (duplicate of mount point `/home/spyndling/bigboy4tb')

(yes i also have my windows fs mounting in the home directory but i don't care as much abt that one)

different locate program are available. Please update your question and include /etc/updatedb.conf, the result of mount | grep /your/mountpoint and which locate is in use : the result of dpkg -l "*locate*" | grep ^.i or similar

What is your Ubuntu version and how exactly is the drive mounted? AFAIK, Ubuntu now uses plocate by default - and although /etc/cron.daily/plocate exists, it does nothing since updating is done by plocate-updatedb.service on a schedule set by plocate-updatedb.timer

... fyi if your updatedb is the plocate version, you can run it with the --debug-pruning option to see exactly what it is omitting ex. /usr/sbin/updatedb.plocate --debug-pruning 2>&1 | grep home (if you run it as an unprivileged user it will not actual do the update, just print the pruning information to stderr)

i have now added all of these edits thank you

OK thanks - so I may be misreading it, but it looks like bigboy4tb is excluded because it is mounted inside an encrypted home directory?

my home directory is not encrypted. nothing in mount is ecryptfs, and both my home partition and the attached drive are ext4

I'm still looking for this. I have to run find / at the moment and ignore every line that says permission denied.

The filesystem type in GNOME Disks was set to "auto"; updatedb was set to prune autofs. Solution: manually set the filesystem type in Disks OR remove autofs from the /etc/updatedb.conf.
